# What is the frequency of Winter Bash 2020 Leaderboard updates?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2020, winter-bash

What is the frequency of Winter Bash 2020 Leaderboard updates?

[Stack Overflow Leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com) still shows me with lesser number of hats which I've collected almost 24 hours ago.

Comment: Since we are past 6 to 8 hours, I guess 6 to 8 days would be the most appropriate update interval.

Comment: It updated for me within a few minutes of being awarded a new hat.   Are you sure all the hats you have are for Stackoverflow?  There might be some that you got on another site only.

Comment: Blame caching, man...

Comment: same, I have 11 hats, but it shows up as 8 on the leaderboard (haven't gotten a new hat within 24 hours)